# Why is rootScope.on called multiple times in my application?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, bootstrap-modal, angularjs-factory, angularjs-rootscope

In my AngularJS application, I have a controller-A and a factory. I am using the following code in factory to call the function in controller-A. In the initial call, the function in controller A's function executes 1 time; on the next call the controller-A's function executes 2 times. Hence the number of times executed get increased for each call. Is it possible to avoid this, please advise me. I have added the factory code and controller-A code below:

**Factory code:**

```
 updateUserData: function (value, action) {
    $("#myModalInsertUser").modal('hide');
    var id = value.Id;
    var params = {};
    params.id = depotId;
    $rootScope.selectedId = params;
    $rootScope.$emit("EVENT_1", {id});
});
```

**Controller-A code:**

```
var listener = $rootScope.$on("EVENT_1", function(event, params, reload) {
    $scope.confirmUserInfo(params);
});

$scope.confirmUserInfo = function(params) {
    $('#myModalConfirmUser').modal('show');

    $('#closeConfirmUser').unbind('click').click(function () {
         $('#myModalConfirmUser').modal('hide');
         var params = $rootScope.selectedId;
         $scope.getUsers(params);
         $scope.$on('$destroy', listener);
     });
}
```

Comment: The problem might be with the placement of the destroy listener. Try placing the destroy at a global level in the controller (same level as the listener).

Comment: I have tried that too, however I am facing same issue again

Comment: Consider using the [UI Bootstrap Modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal) directive. It implements the Bootstrap Modal without using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the event listener to `$scope` and it will be automatically destroyed when the scope is destroyed:

```
̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶l̶i̶s̶t̶e̶n̶e̶r̶ ̶=̶ ̶$̶r̶o̶o̶t̶S̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶o̶n̶(̶"̶E̶V̶E̶N̶T̶_̶1̶"̶,̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶e̶v̶e̶n̶t̶,̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶a̶m̶s̶,̶ ̶r̶e̶l̶o̶a̶d̶)̶ ̶{̶ 
var deregisterFn = $scope.$on("EVENT_1", function(event, params, reload) {
    $scope.confirmUserInfo(params);
});

$scope.confirmUserInfo = function(params) {
    $('#myModalConfirmUser').modal('show');

    $('#closeConfirmUser').unbind('click').click(function () {
         $('#myModalConfirmUser').modal('hide');
         var params = $rootScope.selectedId;
         $scope.getUsers(params);
         ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶o̶n̶(̶'̶$̶d̶e̶s̶t̶r̶o̶y̶'̶,̶ ̶l̶i̶s̶t̶e̶n̶e̶r̶)̶;̶
     });
}
```

The recommended practice is to broadcast events from `$rootScope` and receive them on the `$scope` interested in the event.

---

> is it possible to destroy the listener before the scope gets destroyed?

To remove the listener, simply invoke the de-register function:

```
deregisterFn();
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However is it possible to destroy the listener before the scope gets destroyed

Comment: As per my codebase, scope is not destroyed it loops and I need to destroy the listener once it is executed